# What are the "normal requirements" to hiding?

Tags: dnd-4e, stealth

I have a Rogue Thief in my campaign, currently leveling up to Level 2. As per his build he has available the following power:

> **Fleeting Ghost** Rogue Utility 2
>
> *You are stealthy and fleet of foot at the same time.*
>
> **At-Will · Martial**
>
> **Move Action Personal**
>
> **Prerequisite**: You must be trained in Stealth.
>
> **Effect**: You move up to your speed and
>   can make a Stealth check to hide. You
>   take no penalty to the Stealth check
>   for the movement, though you must
>   still meet the normal requirements to
>   hide.

Now, I know that I should do the Stealth check against the Passive Perceptions of the monsters around her, as per [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3025/does-a-character-have-to-successfully-hide-from-all-opponents-to-be-hidden). But what other requirements, if any, are there? I couldn't find them anywhere (I only found a mention of hiding in the DM Book, in page 141).

I feel really dumb now, having found the data in both the DM Book and the Heroes Of books, under the Stealth Skill. Even though it could be better indexed (there's no mention of "hidden" anywhere), I'm turning this question to Wiki. I don't want RPG.SE to be my index to the books...

Comment: ... I found it now, under Stealth Skill, page 301 of the DM Book.

Comment: @Adriano Note that the stealth rules have undergone some *major* revisions. The compendium lists the changes as 7/28/2008 so if the book you own was published before then, you should look up the latest rules.

Comment: No, the DM book and the Heroes of books were published in november 2010.

Comment: Mods, please, how do I turn this into CW? I can't see the icon/button anywhere.

Comment: Why should this be CW?

Comment: There's no reason to make this a community wiki. If you don't like the question anymore it can be closed or deleted.

Comment: Well, the question is useful, but I don't feel right about gaining rep for basically not knowing how to search the manuals I have right here...

Comment: @Adriano - you gave me an excuse to link the rules of the hiding club, for that I believe you deserve the rep :P.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?447238-The-Rules-of-Hidden-Club-I-Think-I-Failed-A-Spot-Check) is a great guide to all things hiding and hidden in 4e.

The gist of it is that you need Superior Cover or Total Concealment to become hidden.

Superior cover is defined as 3 or more lines from corner to corner from your square to the target square are obstructed. Total Concealment is things like invisibility, dense fog, or total darkness.

Comment: @Adriano - its a must read for rogues, assassins, bow rangers, and anyone else who makes their living in the shadows.

Comment: Oh, yes. Though I'm just the DM in the campaign, not the actual thief.

Comment: While I am not a fan of Stealth rules in either 3.X, PF, or 4E; that was an excellent read. I normally gloss over Stealth rules/rulings, but now I am going to rethink that. Great post!

Comment: +1 Agreed, that is a great article. A complicated stealth maneuver came up during my session the same day I read this, and I was able to sound all smart and stuff!

Comment: @waxeagle Hello!  I ran across this answer when looking up Fleeting Ghost, and it looks like the Rule of Hidden Club link you have is dead now.  Do you know of a more recent, still living link to the rules?

Comment: @ducktapeal, I'd have to poke around to see who has archived wotcs now defunct forums.